# "no such file to load -- redis" exception

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed redis-2.2.2. but I got the exception when require it:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- redis (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from methods.rb:2
```

code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'redis'
```

gem list as follows:

```
activesupport (2.3.5, 2.2.3, 1.4.4)
capistrano (2.5.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.0.10)
dnssd (0.6.0)
fastthread (1.0.1)
fcgi (0.8.7)
ferret (0.11.6)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
rails (2.3.5, 1.2.6)
rake (0.8.3)
RedCloth (4.1.1)
redis (2.2.2)
rmagick (2.13.1)
rspec (1.3.2)
```

Comment: Are you using RVM/RBENV or just "default" Ruby?

Comment: I got this error as well! stupid redis wtf. I never even installed the  damn gem now i can't use rake nor start my server anymore. wtf

Answer (score -1):

Please try this command:

```
sudo gem install redis
```